# calling a mapactivity from another activity

Tags: android, dictionary

I get a class not found exception.

I have included the required entry in manifest file.
The code in current activity is as follows:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MainListingA.this, DrawTheatreMap.class);

            try{
             startActivity(i); 

            }
```

........

The error I get is as follows:

```
07-26 23:03:20.259: WARN/dalvikvm(307): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mobilo.movie.DrawTheatreMap
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307):     at com.mobilo.movie.MainListingA$1.onItemClick(MainListingA.java:101)
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-26 23:03:20.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(307):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

On a standalone basis, the same map activity works fine.

Rgds, PP

Answer (score 12):

You might have the `uses-library`-Tag in the wrong place, at least that was my problem once and the Eclipse / the Google SDK does not complain about that. It has to be under `application`, different to uses-permission which goes beside the application-Tag.

It should look like this:

```
<manifest ...>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application ...>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks, map permission inside of the Application tag!

Answer (score 0):

I usually encounter that error when the application is being run on an emulator that lacks the Google APIs, because Android cannot find the `MapActivity` class.

Comment: Not in this case! I have used Google Maps API to create the project. Also couple of additional details that may help you to review my problem: The error is when I am creating the intent and passing a class that extends MapActivity. 
. Secondly, If I replace this with any other type of activity, the whole thing works. Any idea whats goiong wrong?

Comment: @user395482: "I have used Google Maps API to create the project." -- that has nothing do to with it. "Any idea whats goiong wrong?" -- as I wrote, I usually encounter that error when the application is being run on an emulator that lacks the Google APIs, because Android cannot find the MapActivity class. Make sure your *emulator AVD* has the Google APIs.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have the same problem as @user395482 and your answer seems reasonable. But how do I make sure the emulator have the Google APIs? I created a new AVD and have chosen "Google APIs (Google Inc.)" as the "Target Name". Should that do the trick...?

Comment: @Tim Büthe: Yes. You can also tell by the fact that it has the Google Maps application available from the launcher.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Well, then I have the Google API in place. Seems like my NoClassDefFound comes from somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

Yes putting the using map permission inside of the Application tag fixed it for me in the emulator. v-2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is just change main activity as to extend `MapActivity` and add some unimplemented methods there like

```
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

}
```

So u have a normal activity converted into `MapActivity` but do not add any map views there you are free to use any thing with `MapActivity` as it has all properties of normal activity it worked for me!